# Why should I use nested classes?

Tags: java, scope, inner-classes

When is it feasible to nest classes?
The most common advantage of it that I see is "shared scope" (use of variables across classes).

Is this less attractive/less a best practice than just putting the nested class in it's own file, and passing the arguments through the Constructor?

Comment: Other than the scope advantage, only inner classes can be static and those can be used to store utility methods.

Comment: I personally use it whenever I need a datastructure within my class, but don't necessary won't to publicise this datastructure. Is this best-practice? I don't know, but it works nicely for me. From what I understand is this also used to some extent in "default" java structures like LinkedList ect.

Comment: Funny thing - I always considered nested classes a no-no, like a way of cheating or a hack and less readable. Guess I was wrong

Comment: @DaneBalia I still consider them such. Most situations where one would be tempted to use inner classes should be handled with packages instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several  reasons for using [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), among them:

1. It is a way of **logically grouping** classes that are only used in one place.
2. It increases **encapsulation**.
3. Nested classes can lead to more **readable and maintainable code**.
4. Child to parent class connection is simpler as it **visually illustrates** the variables  and methods of each class.

Comment: Also for exporting deeper functionality than that offered by the enclosing class such as `Iterators` across `Collections`.

Comment: and also debugging is more easy to do

Comment: I'm little skeptical about reason # 2. For encapsulation all languages have access specifiers like private, public protected etc. I am finding it hard to see the concept of nested classes as a way of increasing encapsulation.  You can control the accessibility of a class even when it is not nested. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dd619 how does nesting help in easier debugging. Can you please add a bit more for clarity. Control flow will still jump here and there whenever you call a nested class's APIs. Isn't it?

Comment: @RBT: sorry for late reply..nested classes makes easier to debug code as debug control flow and watch remains in the parent class and also context of nested class show all the variables,watches,expressions and threads in current debugger process(e.g. we can easily compare change of parameter value from parent to nested class).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to those mentioned already, one other benefit is:

- Nested classes also help you achieve **multiple implementation inheritance** (ref: Thinking in Java, page 369 - section "Why inner classes"?). As far I know, there is no other way to achieve it in Java.

Answer (score 1):

According to me the one case i know when nested classes used, When we see one object(OBJ1) is tightly bind with second object(OBJ2) and we can not create first object (OBJ1) without second object(OBJ2). for an example we have employee object and one associated object is salary and we should not able to create salary object independently. because without employee to whom we are going to give salary.
Provide your feedback if i am wrong.

Second case when we are using map or map then we can use nested classes to remove map of map to make code easy to understandable.

third when we want to send data to client side and we can send it in single object having all data :)

when we need something which can define component of outer class or we want to define adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I find private static classes useful when I need to pass a group of related fields into a method and manipulate the same group of data throughout a few method invocations inside a class. Similar to LinkedList.Node class which is not exposed to outside rather used to group links as a single unit.