# How to understand the nested class of Java?

Tags: java

I have learned Java for a month and understand most of the basic syntax. But I still can't truely understand the meaning of nested class. What function does it provide? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide more relevant info for us to understand your problem, otherwise just keep reading tutorials until you have a specific on topic programming question for this site.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why Use Nested Classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14437783/1065197)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons to use nested classes in JAVA. Usually using a nested class isn't necessary but will improve how readable/organized your code is:

It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.

It increases encapsulation: Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.

It can lead to more readable and maintainable code: Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

(from: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

A well explained example can be found here: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075984/java-language/introduction-to-nested-classes-in-java.html