# Static Nested Cass to hold multiple lists within an Outer Class

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am trying to do something similar to the below pseudocode. Does this go against any rules or best practices for using nested classes?

```
public class Foo{
  private list1, list2;

  Bar bar = new Bar(list1, list2);
  // use bar.listA, bar.listB, bar.listC, 
  //bar.listD, bar.listE 

  private static class Bar{
    private list1, list2;
    private listA, listB, listC, listD, listE;

    private Bar(list1, list2) {
        this.list1 = list1;
        this.list2 = list2;
        //logic to split list1 and list2 into 5 lists: listA, listB, listC, listD, listE.
        //initialize the 5 lists
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the nested class for the reasons mentioned by Oracle[or the reasons mentioned by Oracle:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

- It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one
  place
- It increases encapsulation
- It can lead to more readable and
  maintainable code
- And reasons [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14437860/959788)

And I am making the nested class static because I do not need direct access to outer class members.

**Edit**: For the sake of being more specific, some questions in my mind: Should I be using an ENUM instead of nested class? Should I use getters/setters for the 5 lists in the nested class? Is the nested class's constructor the correct place to put the split logic? Is it ok to directly reference nested class's private members in the outer class? etc.

Comment: It's hard to reason about such abstract designs. What real world problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: if 2 lists are passed into the outer instance, I just need an elegant way to split them up into 5 lists and have a handle on them in the outer instance (only). Its just a data transformation process.

Comment: If it's just that then I'd implement a functional solution in the outer class and I wouldn't bother with nested classes or any form of OO design. That is unless you will perform special behaviors on those lists. What is the splitting logic, how these will be used? Do some behaviors only apply to some lists?

Comment: list1 and list2 contain 'event's. And based on the 'type' of events, I split them up into 5 lists. There is not much 'behavior' to these lists, they are just an easy way to hold and access events of those specific types. Could you please give an example of a 'functional solution'? Are you saying just declare listsA to E in the outer class itself, and call a method to take 2 lists and return 5 lists?

Answer (score 1):

> list1 and list2 contain 'event's. And based on the 'type' of events, I
>   split them up into 5 lists

Well, as a general rule of thumb you shouldn't be using constructors for their side effects.

Therefore, I'd probably opt for a `groupEvents` function within `Foo`. If the grouping logic is considerably complex then you could have an `EventGrouper` stateless service that returns a `GroupedEvents` instance or alternatively something like `Map<EventType, List<Event>>`.

E.g.

```
public class Foo {
  private GroupedEvents groupedEvents;

  public Foo(List<Event> list1, List<Event> list2) {
      this.groupedEvents = groupEvents(list1, list2);
  }

  private GroupedEvents groupEvents(List<Event> list1, List<Event> list2) {
      Map<EventType, List<Event>> eventsByType = //perform grouping
      return new GroupedEvents(eventsByType);
  }
}
```

If the logic is complex enough you can move the `groupEvents` function to a stateless `EventGrouper` class which is either nested or not. The important aspect of the design is that the `EventGrouper` shouldn't perform the grouping inside it's constructor.

Now I hear you saying, well isin't `Foo` doing the grouping in it's constructor now? Didin't we just push the problem higher in the chain? Well, while it is true that the grouping does occur during `Foo`'s construction, the client of the `Foo` object is not instantiating a `Foo` instance only for it's grouping side effects (hopefully it does not). The grouping just becomes an implementation detail as part of the `Foo`'s initialization process and the client may not even know that such grouping occurred.

Comment: If i used `GroupedEvents` instead of a `Map<EventType, List<Event>>`, it would just have 5 private lists as its members, correct? And can I create it as a nested static class since it will be used only within Foo?

Comment: @Gadam It may have 5 lists if you will only ever have 5 type of events, but it would be more flexible if it simply had a function such as `eventsOfType(EventType type)` to retrieve the events of a specific type and internally store them in a map. Yes, the class can be nested if you want, but it could also be nested public to allow testing it in unit.